# Angular 2 - Passing parameters into component route using static variable (as opposed to a seperate service)

Tags: angular, routes, components

I would like to launch a route, and pass in a rich object which will describe what it should do.

I started implementing the service approach (which I gathered was best practice).

And then I quickly tried just using a static property on the component I am navigating to, and that worked fine.

So, is this seriously frowned upon?

Having a seperate service to manage the data, just seems a bit like baggage (in this situation).

Source Component

```
import { TargetComponent } from "...";
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { TargetComponentConfig } from '...';

var o = new richObject();
....
TargetComponent.Parameter = o;

this.router.navigate(['/routeForTargetComponent']);
```

Target Component

public static config: TargetComponentConfig;

ngOnInit() {

```
if (config != null) {
    //Make use of the config to set things up
}
```

Comment: Use a service for sharing dynamic data, use the route data to pass static data to the routed component.